# Hide and Unhide Folders Permanently

Tags: 14.04

In my local drive for a folder,when i add **'.'** followed by the folder name, and press **ctrl+H**, the folder gets invisible, but once if i close that drive and open it again the hidden files are automatically visible without pressing **ctrl+H**. So how to hide a folder permanently.

Comment: Open nautilus->edit->preference->views. unselect the "show hidden and backup files"

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to manually switch off the "." files being able to be viewed by going to the "edit" menu -> Preferences and switching off the "Show hidden and backup files" option.

I think this should now permanently hide the files.
Hope this helps.